# Is there an effecient way to test if a .onion link is alive

Tags: python, tcp, hyperlink, tor

I'm writting a link **scraper** but it takes several minutes for my program to recognize a link as dead. This substantially reduces the efficiency of my program but I can't ping over tor because it only accepts TCP communications. My program is in python but it wouldnt be an issue to switch to a different language more suited to this task if that is required.

```
proxies = {
        'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
        'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'

}
link_error = False
class find_links_on_page:
    def get_raw(self):
        print(search_link)
        print('working1a')
        global link_error
        try:
            raw =requests.get(search_link, proxies=proxies)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            link_error = True
        print('working1b')
        if link_error == False:
            stat = raw.status_code
            global soup
            rawd = raw.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rawd, 'lxml')
            global link_raw
            print('working1c')
            link_raw = soup.find_all('a')
            print(link_raw)
            return link_raw
        else:
            print('not working')
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: sorry kind havent made very many posts